# Why does "$i | sed" not work?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, terminal

I have this code:

```
if [ $i | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/" = "/" ]
then
    echo "folder"
else
    echo "file"
fi
```

where `$i` is something like this

```
app4/
```

The code above should get the last char of the string and check if it is a slash (`/`), but it tells me:

> ./str: line 12: =app4/: File or directory doesn't exist

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, do not cross post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89561/impossible-to-compare-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the value of `$i` in to see the exact command you're trying to run:

```
app4/ | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"
```

This doesn't work because `app4/` isn't a command. You're trying to pipe `app4/` into `sed`, so you need to use something that outputs `app4/`:

```
echo app4/ | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"
```

This works, but you don't really need to use `sed` for this; `bash` has quite a few string manipulation tools. For example, `${i#}` will give you the length of `$i`, and `${i:j}` will give you a substring starting at `j`, so `${i:$((${i#}-1))}` will give you the last character.

The easiest way to do what you're trying is probably with `${i%/}`. This will return `$i`, but will strip off a `/` from the end if there is one:

```
$ i="app4"; echo ${i%/}
app4
$ i="app4/"; echo ${i%/}
app4
```

Thus:

```
if [ "${i%/}" = "$i" ]
then
    echo "file"
else
    echo "folder"
fi
```

However, if all you *really* want is to know if `$i` is a valid directory, you can just use:

```
if [ -d "$i" ]
```

Comment: perfect! i can't use -d because i need to create that directory

Comment: Then create the dir if it is missing with: if [ ! -d $i ]; then mkdir -p $i; fi

Comment: @Johan: Or just `mkdir -p $i`, which does nothing if it's already a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check if the variable ends in / is:

```
[[ $i = */ ]]
```

..although as Johan said, you can just check whether it exists and create it if not. That should however be quoted properly:

```
if [[ ! -d $i ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$i" || exit 1
fi
```

We don't need to quote expansions inside [[ .. ]] which, along with its greater utility and speed, makes it much nicer to use; we definitely need to quote the parameter to mkdir.